# Exercise on Metric space

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

I hve this exercise it is very simple but i don't know how to write the answer

Let $A$ be a nonempty set in $(E,d)$, for $\varepsilon>0$ we note $$V_{\varepsilon}(A)=\{x\in E, d(x,A)<\varepsilon\}$$ how to prove that

- $\displaystyle\bigcap_{\varepsilon>0} V_{\varepsilon}(A)=\displaystyle\bigcap_{\frac1n\in\mathbb{N}^*} V_{\frac1n}(A)$ and that
- $ V_{\varepsilon}(A)=\displaystyle\bigcup_{x\in A} B(x,\varepsilon),$ for all $x>0$

Thank you very much.

Comment: A nice way to prove that two sets $A$ and $B$ are equal is to show that an element of $A$ is necessarily an element of $B$ and vice versa.

Comment: I think in second statements there should be $\bigcup$ not $\bigcap$

Comment: hhhh i know this but if i have $\forall \varepsilon>0, \inf_{y\in A} d(x,y)<\varepsilon$ how to introduce $\frac1n$ you  think that i dn't try to prove this ??

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let $x \in \bigcap_{\varepsilon>0} V_{\varepsilon}(A)$, then $\forall \, \epsilon >0$ $x \in V_{\varepsilon}(A)$. Using the Archimedean property we get that for each $\epsilon >0$, $\exists \, n_{\epsilon} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n_{\epsilon}\epsilon >1$. See if you can proceed from here.

Comment: we have $\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists n\in \mathbb{N}^*, \varepsilon>\frac1n$ but we need $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}^*$

Comment: Note that if $m < n$ then $V_{\frac{1}{n}} \subseteq V_{\frac{1}{m}}$.

Comment: I don't understand you $\varepsilon$ is a positive real so if i have $\inf_{y\in A} d(x,y)=d(x,A)<\varepsilon >\frac1/n$ how to obtain that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}^*, d(x,A)<\frac1n$

Answer (score 0):

I'll just write some hits so you can finish it

Hints to the first equality:

- Note that the right side is a subset of the left side
- If $\epsilon>0$ then there exists an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $1/n<\epsilon$. Use this to prove the other inclusion.

Hints to the second equality (which has $\cap$ instead of $\cup$):

$x\in V_x(a)\iff d(x,A)<\epsilon\iff \exists a\in A: d(x,a)<\epsilon$

Answer (score 0):

I will prove the first one and leave the second one for you.

As @Matthe Leingang suggest, we first show that 
$$\bigcap_{\epsilon>0}V_\epsilon (A)\subset \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb N}V_\frac{1}{n} (A) \tag 1$$

Take $x\in \bigcap_{\epsilon>0}V_\epsilon (A)$ and we want to prove that $x\in \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb N}V_\frac{1}{n} (A)$. Fix arbitrary $n\in \mathbb N$, we can always have $\epsilon_n>0$ such that $\epsilon_n<1/n$. Because $x\in \bigcap_{\epsilon>0}V_\epsilon (A)$ and hence in particular $x\in V_{\epsilon_0}(A)$ and thus $x\in V_\frac{1}{n}(A)$. Therefore, we have $(1)$. The other direction is similar.

Comment: please why you fixe $n$ and why there exists $\varepsilon_n$ directly ? thank you